# CNTK - LSTM Recurrence with input values from previous layers

Tags: lstm, recurrence, cntk

I'm struggling to implement my model with LSTM cells in recurrence. I want to use output from my dense layer as input into recurrence sequence but i can't figure out how to do this.

Here is sample code of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
import cntk as C
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

x = C.input_variable(a.shape, name='Input Variable')

m = C.layers.Convolution1D(filter_shape=3,
                         num_filters=4,
                         strides=(2),
                         reduction_rank=0,
                         pad=True, name='Convolutional layer')(x)

m = C.layers.Dense(5, activation=None, name='Dense layer')(m)


m = C.layers.RecurrenceFrom(C.layers.LSTM(3,name='LSTM Layer'), name='Reccurence Layer')(m)
```

and here's picture of how i imagine it should look ([based on this tutorial](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/CNTK_106A_LSTM_Timeseries_with_Simulated_Data.html#Network-modeling)):

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F9t5.png)

Output from console after running the code:

```
>>> m = C.layers.RecurrenceFrom(C.layers.LSTM(3,name='LSTM Layer'), name='Reccurence Layer')(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Maros\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\ops\functions.py", line 374, in __call__
    arg_map = self.argument_map(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maros\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\ops\functions.py", line 263, in argument_map
    raise TypeError("CNTK Function expected {} arguments, got {}".format(len(params), len(args) + len(kwargs)))
TypeError: CNTK Function expected 3 arguments, got 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `C.layers.Recurrence` instead of `C.layers.RecurrenceFrom`. The latter is used to establish a recurrent layer with a sequence input **and a dynamic initial value**, while the former requires only a sequence input. See `help(C.layers.Recurrence)` for details.

Comment: You are right. I had problem while using `C.layers.Recurrence` so i figured the `C.layers.RecurrenceFrom` is what i needed. After some trial and error i managed to solve my problem while using `C.ops.to_sequence` function to convert my output from dense layer into sequence for `C.layers.Recurrence`. 
Hope it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my sample code after the changes.

```
import cntk as C
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

x = C.input_variable(a.shape, name='Input Variable')

m = C.layers.Convolution1D(filter_shape=3,
                         num_filters=4,
                         strides=(2),
                         reduction_rank=0,
                         pad=True, name='Convolutional layer')(x)

m = C.layers.Dense((5,1), activation=None, name='Dense layer')(m)

m = C.ops.to_sequence(m)

m = C.layers.Recurrence(C.layers.LSTM(3,name='LSTM Layer'), name='Reccurence Layer')(m)
```